# Airflow DAG stop when triggered another one

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to know if there is a smart way to stop a dag when another one is triggered by the scheduler and resume it when the other ends.

E.g.

- manually starts DAG_1 at 9am that runs for 6 hours
- the scheduler trigger the DAG_2 at 11am that runs for 1 hour
- stops DAG_1
- DAG_2 ends
- DAG_1 resume from the same point it has been stopped

Comment: You could probably do something janky with the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) and [data aware scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html), although I'm not sure I'd recommend it. What's the use case?